# Strategy for JS Asyncronic Pagination

Tags: javascript, jquery

I got at my home page a list `<ul>` of datas. Right now I load them at once, and want to implement pagination cause sometimes the list reaches 500-1000 items, and this postpone the site and create bad ux.

I can use available plugins, but all deliver the same bad ux - on clicking the user feels this glinch, this pause, this postponing of data streaming.

[I can present in the UI some preloader or msg](http://datatables.net/release-datatables/examples/server_side/defer_loading.html), but I wish to avoid it. I wish to make this preloading transparent to the user.

I thought on loading at start the first item only, and than when user clicks the *next* button, I'll load every time the next 2 (or 3) 'pages'.

I am worried regarding the following situation: how to handle the data when the user will click very fast on the nav buttons. how to prevent UI mistakes.

One more subject - Caching. How can I improve my performance?  What techniques can I use, if needed at all?

Thank you!

Comment: ¿What language/stack/framework are you using below that JS?

Comment: Jquery, and in house lib. Arround is asp.net mvc